# How to render ONE of multiple components conditionally that works well with React's change detector?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component

In my CRUD app, I have implemented several reuseable components like a "generic" `DialogComponent` and several non-reusable components. I have come across many scenarios where I need to (on the same page) either:

a) render one of multiple different non-reusable components conditionally like so:

```
return(
  <>
    { condition111 && <Component_A>}
    { condition222 && <Component_B>}
  </>
)
```

or b) pass different props to the same component conditionally. `DialogComponent` contains a form which renders different fields based on whether it is an ADD or EDIT dialog (depending on the props passed in):

```
return(<>
      {
        openAddDialog &&
        <DialogComponent
          rowAction={Utils.RowActionsEnum.Add}
          setOpenDialog={setOpenAddDialog} />
      }
      {
        openEditDialog &&
        <DialogComponent
          rowAction={Utils.RowActionsEnum.Edit}
          setOpenDialog={setOpenEditDialog} />
      }
</>)
```

^ This works fine, but idk if it is best practice to do it this way.

I was thinking maybe I could render a function that returns a component conditionally like below. **QUESTION 1: Is this a good/bad idea in terms of React rendering?**

```
export const GridComponent = (props) => {
...
const [gridName, setgridName] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  setGridName(props.gridName);
}, []);

const renderGrid = () => {
 switch (gridName) {
    case GridNameEnum.Student:
      return <StudentGridComponent />;

    case GridNameEnum.Employee:
      return <EmployeeGridComponent />;

    default:
      return <h1>Grid rendering error.</h1>;
  }
};

return(<>
  { renderGrid() }
</>)
}
```

**QUESTION 2: What is the best way to handle this conditional rendering of a) one of multiple different components and b) same component rendered conditionally with different props?** (Note: these are "child components" to be rendered on the same page)

Comment: Is there something wrong with how you're already doing it? Personally, I would create different components for each configuration, rather than one component that renders multiple conditionally. Why do you need `GridComponent` when you can just type `StudentGridComponent` directly?

Comment: @ChrisHamilton - Nothing wrong, it works fine, but idk if it is best practice to do it the way it did.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton - GridComponent is the parent component. It has other properties and functionalities in it that I have not shown here.
What do you think of Question 1 in the description?

Comment: Perhaps you should more specific about what these properties and functionalities are, currently the pattern you showed doesn't really make sense. Of course that style of conditional rendering is fine, there's examples of it in the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator

Comment: @ChrisHamilton - no, I mean the switch-statement return from function renderGrid(). Is that good practice? That is not in the docs.

Comment: **Perhaps you should more specific about what these properties and functionalities are, currently the pattern you showed doesn't really make sense.**

Comment: @ChrisHamilton - What is there to not make sense? I provided all the relevant info and asked a simple question: "I want to do `return(<> { renderGrid() } </>)`. Is this a good or bad idea?" That's it. The other properties and functionalities don't matter.

Comment: Because you could just write `<StudentGridComponent />`. How is that better than `<GridComponent gridName={GridNameEnum.Student}`?

Comment: And why do you need this component when you could just export the function `renderGrid(gridName)`? Without more details, seems like this is just a question of personal preference.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton - How about this, just answer this extremely simple question: Imagine GridComponent has nothing else except for what I laid out in the description. I just want to do that way (with the switch statement and renderGrid()). Is there any React performance-related concerns that this code will impact (maybe with the v-DOM or any unnecessary re-renders by calling `renderGrid()` too many times)? If you need to know about Student and Employee grids, imagine they are just simple `<table>`s as shown here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Answer (score 1):

You're asking two questions in one here and for opinions which is generally frowned upon but for the sake of trying to provide some guidance let's approach this in a functional way.

QUESTION 1: Is this a good/bad idea in terms of React rendering?:

It's fine because you only do one OR the other, never both but I'd still use a ternary if I were writing this myself to make it very clear that only one of these situations can ever occur:

```js
enum DialogOptions {
    Add,
    Edit,
    Delete
}

interface MyComponentProps {
    DialogOption: DialogOptions
}

const MyComponent = ({ DialogOption }: MyComponentProps) => {
    return DialogOption === DialogOptions.Add ? 'Add' : DialogOption === DialogOptions.Edit ? 'Edit' : DialogOption === DialogOptions.Delete ? 'Delete' : null
}
```

QUESTION 2: What is the best way to handle this conditional rendering of a) one of multiple different components and b) same component rendered conditionally with different props?

There are many ways you could do this and people will have different opinions. In the limited situation you've described your grid component obfuscates what is happening and means I have to dig in the code which is not helpful. It would be cleaner to:

1. Use a generic `grid` component which can be applied in multiple places (if this is possible, otherwise ignore this).
2. Create your `StudentGridComponent` and `EmployeeGridComponent` components which implement the generic `grid` component, or their own unique grid component if nothing can be shared.
3. Call the appropriate grid directly where it is required (whether this is a page or another component) using the ternary suggestion above (but put this inside your `return` and conditionally render the appropriate component or return some sort of empty message)

In terms of the way you've built your grid component I don't see the point of this. At the time where you're rendering your grid you should already be conditionally rendering either of the grids because you know you have that data, or you don't. There's no need for the complex state logic you've introduced within the grid component itself.